# How can I change the value of a cfquery result before exporting to Excel?

Tags: coldfusion, spreadsheet

I already have a working code to export a CFQuery into an Excel file. However, I can't seem to figure out how to change the result before being written to the spreadsheet. The RSVP column has Y or N as its value. When I export the data, I wish for the cell to say Accept or Decline instead.

Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

Here is my current code:

```
<cfscript>
    // Get data from a query
    Query=QueryExecute("SELECT NAME, RSVP FROM TABLE",[],{datasource="DBASE"});

    // Create a spreadsheet object with sheetname
    spObj=spreadsheetNew("Query",true);

    // Add rows with data from query result. The data start from row 1, col 1. The spreadsheet will have column names.
    SpreadSheetAddRow(spObj, 'NAME,RSVP');

    //Make the header bold
    SpreadsheetformatRow(spObj,{bold=true},1);

    //Create the Spreadsheet
    SpreadSheetAddRows(spObj,Query,2,1,true,["STRING"],false);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: In SQL, use CASE to return "Accept" or "Decline" instead of Y and N.

Comment: @Trose Your answer helped! I was able to get my Accept/Decline on the spreadsheet. However, I can't find the link to accept your answer. Once I find it I will "accept" it. Thank you!

Comment: @TRose, I suggest that you answer the question again, as an answer, as opposed to a comment.

Comment: @airpolgas added an answer proper for you. Thanks!

Comment: From a database design perspective, if you have a field that can contain one of two answers (or NULL if needed), then I'd go with a Boolean datatype rather than a single character "y/n". Booleans are usually much cleaner and easier to work with than parsing meaning from a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this as an answer. In SQL you'll want to return "Accept" or "Decline" (or whatever text you fancy) using a CASE statement.

In your case it'll probably look a lot like this:

```
SELECT
  [Name],
  CASE WHEN [RSVP] LIKE 'Y' THEN 'ACCEPT' ELSE 'DECLINE' END AS Response
FROM
  [TableName]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!